# The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on <ServerName>

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I am having a lot of trouble setting up transactional replication on my test server.  I am running SQL Server 2008 SP2.

I am able to create a transactional publication.  The snapshot agent works fine and subscribing to the publication works fine as well.  The problem that I get is that the log reader agent fails with the error:

The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on [ServerName]

The snapshot and log reader agents are run under a windows account with administrator privileges on the domain and sysadmin privileges on the sql server.  I have also tried running the agents under the SQL agent profile.  I have tried executing sp_replflush and restarting the SQL agent.  I have also tried increasing -LoginTimeout to 500 and -ReadBatchSize to 10.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons  that can cause this, but for me recently the problem was that both databases were owned by a domain account. As soon as I switched them both to owned by "sa", it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing output verbose level to 4 to see any additional info.chnanging readbatch size will not help if it is a single transaction.